# CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates, certificates

I am trying to upgrade a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server to 16.04. But when ever I ran `sudo http_proxy="http://usrid:pwd@proxy...mcom:8080" apt update` it returns following error:

#### Error message

```
Err http://apt.llvm.org llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0/main amd64 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err http://apt.llvm.org llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0/main i386 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err http://apt.llvm.org llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0/main amd64 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err http://apt.llvm.org llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0/main i386 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0/main/binary-i386/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/dists/llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0/main/binary-i386/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

#### Solutions tried but still no luck:

1. update `ca-certificates`;
2. `apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`;
3. check `sources.list`, it is the default ubuntu trusty source;

#### Current Ubuntu 14.04

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

I was wondering if this problem is related to my proxy set up. But I have tried using proxy to upgrade before and it worked fine. Please let me know if you have any suggestions! I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Trusty tahr is EOL so best you backup and download the latest LTS...

Comment: @Geogre Udosen But I upgraded another14.04 distro server before, same process & no bugs. So I fiured the LTS wouldn't be a issue